# How can I get the collection “community” of the first data

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId('58d0789eb9031ac824000001'),
    "propertyId": "property001",
    "title": "test1",
    "imageUrl": "",
    "contact": "tom",
    "contactphone": "045182321127",
    "community": [
        {
            "_id": "123456789",
            "communityId": "community001",
            "title": "communitytest",
            "imageUrl": "",
            "contact": "tom",
            "contactphone": "045182321127"          
        },
        {
            "communityId": "community002",
            "title": "communitytest",
            "imageUrl": "",
            "contact": "jack",
            "contactphone": "045182321127"  
                },
                {           
        },
        {
            "communityId": "community003",
            "title": "communitytest3",
            "imageUrl": "",
            "contact": "sfva",
            "contactphone": "045182321127"      
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get the collection `“community”` of the first data. I use `"db.test.find({"community.communityId":"community001"})"` return all data of the `"community"`

Comment: It's not clear what do you mean by *first data*. Please add expected result and query which you have now

Answer (score 0):

Use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) if you want to limit content of array:

```
db.test.find({}, {community: { $elemMatch: {communityId: "community001"}}})
```

You can keep your filter if you want to filter documents by those which only have required item in community array.

Comment: HI Sergey - I think the crucial thing you need to emphasise is that you are adding a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/); the OP doesn't seem to be familiar with projections yet.